# How to remove redundant headers from SOAP request using Zeep

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, netsuite, zeep

When attempting to use Zeep to create a SOAP request for product search from Netsuite webservice (WSDL https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2016_1_0/netsuite.wsdl), I use the following code:

```
result = client.service.search(searchRecord=item_search, _soapheaders={
    'searchPreferences': search_preferences,
    'applicationInfo': app_info,
    'passport': passport,
})
```

But zeep generates XML of the form:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
      <ns0:passport xmlns:ns0="urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
         <ns1:email xmlns:ns1="urn:core_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">some@email.com</ns1:email>
         <ns2:password xmlns:ns2="urn:core_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">somepassword</ns2:password>
         <ns3:account xmlns:ns3="urn:core_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">12345</ns3:account>
         <ns4:role xmlns:ns4="urn:core_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" internalId="1234" type="role" />
      </ns0:passport>
      <ns5:tokenPassport xmlns:ns5="urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" />
      <ns6:applicationInfo xmlns:ns6="urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
         <ns6:applicationId>ABCDE</ns6:applicationId>
      </ns6:applicationInfo>
      <ns7:partnerInfo xmlns:ns7="urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" />
      <ns8:searchPreferences xmlns:ns8="urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
         <ns8:bodyFieldsOnly>false</ns8:bodyFieldsOnly>
         <ns8:returnSearchColumns>true</ns8:returnSearchColumns>
         <ns8:pageSize>20</ns8:pageSize>
      </ns8:searchPreferences>
   </soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <ns0:search xmlns:ns0="urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
         <ns0:searchRecord xmlns:ns3="urn:common_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:ItemSearchBasic">
            <ns3:isInactive>
               <ns2:searchValue xmlns:ns2="urn:core_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">true</ns2:searchValue>
            </ns3:isInactive>
         </ns0:searchRecord>
      </ns0:search>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Note that the generated header contains parameters which I didn't set like tokenPassport and partnerInfo. The added tokenPassport together with passport leads the Netsuite endpoint to throw an Ambiguous Authentication error.

Could someone kindly point me to how to remove tokenPassport from generated XML SOAP headers?

Comment: author of zeep here. This might just be a bug in zeep. Could you report an issue and attach an example script as documented at http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/reporting_bugs.html#errors-when-creating-the-request ? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually remove tokenPassport to get it to work.

```
# Manually remove tokenPassport that's being incorrectly added by zeep
from lxml import etree
token_passport = envelope.xpath('//x:tokenPassport',
namespaces {'x':'urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'})
if token_passport:
token_passport[0].getparent().remove(token_passport[0])
```

https://github.com/procurify/python-zeep/commit/9570007707852caf8e483d4fa9b2b125e73eff1c#diff-e4abfefd4d94bc00a36412733fc6a372